# Getting a value from drop down to Ajax auto complete event

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have country list in a dropdown list and I want to bind the table name with the autocomplete event of the text box as below:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    public static string[] sql(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conx"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [city_name]FROM [pinfo].[dbo].["+ddl_country.selecteditem.text+"]", con);
        ad.Fill(ds, "data");
        con.Close();
        string[] main= new string[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(prefixText.ToLower()))
            {
                Array.Resize(ref main,main.Length + 1);
                main[main.Length - 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                if (main.Length == 20)
                    break;
            }

        }
        Array.Sort(main);
        return main;

        //return default(string[]);
    }
```

especially

this line

```
 SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [city_name]FROM [pinfo].[dbo].["+ddl_country.selecteditem.text+"]", con);
```

I want the dropdown value in the above string.

Comment: You must pass this value as parametre, and read it the moment you call this function

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: i got answer by passing parameter useing context key.